# How to make a listview cells not traversable with arrow keys?

Tags: listview, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a ListView and would like to disable the traversal with arrow keys so that only a `MouseEvent` would change the selected item. I was going to use a `TraversalEngine`, but it seems as though that is deprecated. What is the best way to prevent the traversal? I get that I can do `ListView.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>)`, but I'm not sure how to prevent the traversal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
listView.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
         event.consume();
    }
});
```

Comment: Or, same thing but way more concise, `listView.setOnKeyPressed(Event::consume);`

Answer (score 0):

The answer marked correct doesn't seem to work for me but I found success using an event filter instead as shown in the simple example code below.

```
ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("foo", "bar");
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(items);
listView.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, Event::consume);
```